# How to open .epub files on Windows?

Tags: windows, epub

In former times, when wanting to read an .epub, I'd use Microsoft Edge. Thing is, as of last year, [Microsoft Edge no longer supports .epubs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517840/microsoft-edge-download-an-epub-app-to-keep-reading).

So, I most likely have to go with any third-party reader. What free option should I go for that's not a [browser extension like EPUBReader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epubreader/jhhclmfgfllimlhabjkgkeebkbiadflb?hl=en)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to go with [sumatrapdf](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) on most of my windows boxen. Handles Epub (and is a pretty competent pdf, mobi and cb* reader)

Its got a simple UI with options to fit width and show pages continously, or by page.

[image]

Its also customisable by editing a text file and you can easily customise it from the black on cream default

[image]
<sub>[A Modest Proposal by Jonathan Swift](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1080)</sub>

---

I've seen some people using others like [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/), [Ebook Reader](https://icecreamapps.com/Ebook-Reader/) or [FBReader](https://fbreader.org/). So, it's a matter of selecting the one you like best.

Comment: This app doesn't even support zoom. I changed both text size and zoom level on epub but non of them work

Answer (score 5):

There is also a program called `Calibre`. It's an ebook manager and library like application. It provides an epub reader, or can shell out to other types of readers if configured.

- https://calibre-ebook.com/

I'm a huge fan of this application since it's a FOSS application.

Answer (score 1):

To promote all sides, Adobe does provide an epub reader called Adobe Digital Editions.

- https://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions.html

Sometimes there are ebooks, or epubs that are only able to be opened in this application. Those are generally epubs with DRM on them. Google around a bit on this one.

Answer (score 1):

[Ice Cream Ebook Reader](https://icecreamapps.com/Download-Ebook-Reader/) is a good option, it renders ebooks better than Calibre.